# What is the effect of a statement with the && operator with boolean evaluation in a javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a code snippet out of the [mixItUp jQuery plugin](http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/iwcap) (full code in the link for reference).  What is the point of having a statement that can potentially evaluate to false inside a for loop?  Does that mean you break out of the loop?  Specifically I'm wondering about this line: *(group.tracker === false) && done++;*

```
concatenate: function(){
var self = this,
      cache = '',
      crawled = false,
      checkTrackers = function(){
    var done = 0;

    for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
      (group.tracker === false) && done++;
    }

    return (done < self.groups.length);
  },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a concise way of writing

```
if (group.tracker === false)
    done++;
```

The statement does not effect the mechanics of the loop surrounding it.

There's no real benefit to using that style of coding; there's going to be no meaningful performance difference either way. It's just a preference.

Answer (score 4):

That line of code is using a **lazy evaluation** thing.

JavaScript works here just as it was this piece of code:

```
if (group.tracker === false)
    done++;
```

How does that work: let's think of this line as of logic expression.

We check first part: `(group.tracker === false)`. If it's result is `false` then we know, that whole expression will result in `false` (because of `&&` operator). So we don't have to run second part of code.

However, if it's `true` than we need to run the second piece of code, to check if that is `true` also.

That's how it basically works